# PHP Cookie value not echoing anything

Tags: php, cookies

I am testing out PHP cookies for the first time and according to the W3Schools tutorial I thought I was doing everything right but the value of my cookie is nothing.

Here is my whole form validation code which the cookie code is in in process.php:

```
function validate_post_form() {
    global $postMsg;

    $valid = true;
    if ( $_POST['course'] == null || $_POST['course'] == "") {
        $postMsg .= " You must choose a course.";
        $valid = false;
    }
    if ( $_POST['convert'] == null || $_POST['convert'] == "") {
        $postMsg .= " You must choose to convert the text or not.";
        $valid = false;
    }
    if ( $_POST['input'] == null || $_POST['input'] == "") {
        $postMsg .= " You must enter an text input to process.";
        $valid = false;
    } 

    $set = $_POST['set'];

    // check if cookies or session radio button is set
    if ($set == "cookie") {
        $value = "<img src=\"../BENSON_Cookies/PleaseNoDeleteMyCookies.JPG\" />";
        $cookie = setcookie("Cookie", $value, time()+3600);
    } else if ($set == "session") {
        echo "You have selected session.";
    }

    if ($cookie) {
        echo "The cookie is set.";
    } else {
        echo "The cookie is not set.";
    }

    echo $postMsg;
    return $valid;
} // End validate_post_form() function
```

Here is my form code which is on the index.php page:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" target="preview">
Set: <input type="radio" name="set" value="cookie">Cookies
    <input type="radio" name="set" value="session">Session<br>
    <span style="color:red;">*</span>Course: 
            <select name="course" class="form-control">
                <option value="">Choose:</option>
                <option value="HTML">HTML</option>
                <option value="CSS">CSS</option>
                <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
                <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
            </select><br>
    <span style="color:red;">*</span>Convert Text? 
            <input type="radio" name="convert" value="Yes">Yes
            <input type="radio" name="convert" value="No">No<br>
    <span style="color:red;">*</span>Text Input:<br>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="input" placeholder="Input text here."></textarea><br>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The process.php page is being sent to a target iframe named preview as you can see from the form code. If the cookie is selected then I want it to set the cookie, and print the value of the cookie which is a picture of cookie monster.

The new output is :

```
The cookie is not set.
```

Comment: Try `$set=$_POST['set']; if ($set == "cookie") {`

Comment: didn't do anything. :C

Comment: Your edit has `$cookie_msg` but it's a stray variable.

Comment: You need to do `if ($set == "session")...` and not `else if ($_POST['set'] == "session")` anyway, see the answer below. Take it up with that person. I believe I've solved it already. Good luck with that.

Comment: The correct way to get a cookie is $_COOKIE[$cookiename]

Comment: From the dox: *If output exists prior to calling this function, setcookie() will fail and return FALSE*. So are you printing anything before setting the cookie?

Comment: ok i got rid of the $cookie_msg variable and just changed that to an echo statement. also fixed the '($set == "session")..' still not setting though

Comment: so i need to say 'echo $_COOKIE[$Cookie]' to call it instead? I'll try it..

Comment: @onetrickpony I'm not to my understanding. I have updated my code above to show the whole form validation code that the setcookie() is in.

Comment: I would recommend you to set the domain and path for the cookie to be set.  setcookie($cookiename,$value,$expiry,$path,$domain,$secure,$httponly);

Comment: I am using my localhost:8888 and MAMP currently. If that means anything.

Comment: check my answer, i have edited it to show the setcookie example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    You cannot see the cookie set until the script executes and then if you put 
     the println in the next page , you should be able to see it.

Here is the setcookie example :
$cookiename ='mycookie';
$value="mytestvalue";
$expiry=time()+3600;
$path="/";
$domain="my.domain.name";
$secure=true;
$httponly=true;
setcookie($cookiename,$value,$expiry,$path,$domain,$secure,$httponly);


 Use the following to access the cookie :
     $mycookie = $_COOKIE["mycookie"];

 Another easier way to check the cookies is to use the firebug tool on 
 firefox or plugins like editthiscookie on chrome.
```

Comment: how do i check the cookies with firebug? I have it but never knew I could do that.

Comment: right click on the firefox browser and select inspect with firebug.  And in the firebug window that opens up on the bottom of the browser, there is a tab called cookies.  click on that and you should be able to see all the cookies set by the various websites you visited on it.

Comment: This worked! Still not sure what was happening before that was messing it up. 0_o Thank you!

Comment: Hello, if my cookie is protected, inside a function, that is inside a class how do I access that cookie in my html?

Answer (score 1):

What it looks like to me is that it's not acessing $_POST['set'] variable right, so it doesn't execute the cookie code. I think the problem is that you didn't close your input tags, and your browser is now going insane from it. Try closing it and see what happens.